# Swift 3.0 Calendar dateComponents "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to fetch the components of a date. This expression below is throwing an error, "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". This was auto-generated from Swift 2 to Swift 3 compiler.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let eventDate = formatter.date(from: "12/19/2016")

let calendar = NSCalendar.current

// this is throwing the error
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: eventDate!, options: [])
```

How can I fetch the date components in swift 3?

My intent is to create a countdown clock to a certain date (eventdate) from today's date.

Comment: `NSCalendar` has no such method as `dateComponents...`. It has several `components...` methods though. And why use `NSCalendar` instead of `Calendar`?

Comment: Use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar`, and remove `options` parameter.

Comment: @Rob, thank you, that worked!